# When the scores don't add up

Tags: support, reputation

I am finding that what my reputation points section says and what is in the question area are sometimes different.  Example: I up voted a question and I got -1 for downvoteing it.; It says in my rep that I got 1 down vote and 2 up votes but the answer has 0 votes next to it.

I am sure that if you all pay attention it is happening to you to.  Recommendations?

Comment: Care to give us some example of these questions so we can take a look? Also, probably not related, have you tried a rep recalc at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/reputation ?

Comment: Why do Music Tapes and CDs have the message

Comment: There are others as well, I can't compile a whole list as once I noticed it I found many.

Comment: Another one: I voted it up and they gave me -1 for voting down the question about who should we give Tzedaka to.

Comment: Also, do we get points for up voted comments? If so, I have 8 upvotes for a comment about Christmans music and no points.

Comment: As I said I have even more examples.  Check out your list, I am sure others are having the same problem.

Comment: Comment upvotes affect display only, not reputation. Comments are second-class citizens by design.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, re "Comment upvotes affect display only, not reputation": True, but they also yield badges.

Comment: @msh210, good point.

Comment: @msh210 More like 'badge' singular.

Answer (score 4):

On your [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11962/2) answer, I see one upvote and one downvote from other users, for a total of 0 votes. On your [reputation tally](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1022/morah-hochman?tab=reputation), I see under yesterday (Dec. 3) +10/-2 for one upvote and one downvote on that question. This is all based on other people voting on your post, not on your votes on other peoples' posts.

This all seems consistent to me. Am I missing something?